# Unable to boot Ubuntu 20.04 on iMac 12,2 (i7, Mid-2011) without kernel option `nomodeset`

Tags: 20.04, radeon, mac, xserver, kms

I am struggling with an iMac 27" from 2011 with a Radeon 6970M GPU.

Without the `nomodeset` kernel parameter the display turns black when KMS kicks in.

With `i915.modeset=1 radeon.modeset=0` the boot continues but the screen turns again black with a single `_` in the top left corner when the display manager is started. Actually, the display manager is up and running and I can blindly launch a terminal and reboot the system.

I also tried to disable the discrete GPU as mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/blackgate/48c57e3ac5f82a1b43c6c2cb8be98fec) by adding the following snippet to the GRUB config:

```
    outb 0x728 1
    outb 0x710 2
    outb 0x740 2
    outb 0x750 0
```

I furthermore played with the `video=SVIDEO-1:d` kernel parameter as mentioned [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/intel_graphics#Blank_screen_during_boot,_when_%22Loading_modules%22). Unfortunately, also without any success.

I am still facing the following issues:

- graphics output only with `nomodeset` but then of course no hardware acceleration when decoding videos etc.
- suspend/resume does not work
- backlight control does not work - even when `acpi_backlight=native` is set as described [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/IMac_Aluminum#Brightness_control_on_a_2011_27_inch_iMac).

What bugs me is that Ubuntu apparently once worked on the iMac 12,2 as summarized [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/iMac12-2/Natty) - at least *suspend*.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You weren't specific as to which 20.04 ISO you were using; given it's old hardware - did you try an ISO with the GA kernel stack (LTS releases have two kernel stack options; we don't even know if you're asking about server or desktop, so please be specific with questions).

Comment: I tried the GA kernel and the desktop version. But the problem that I am describing seems to be pretty well known for Linux on Macs and quite independent from the distro used. Unfortunately none of the existing solutions worked for me so far.